Can't create new Project in Google Actions
I want to ceate a new Project in Google Actions, but after i type in my Project Name and go to smart home i get a message, that "Something went wrong when creating your project. please try again later." Does anybody have an idea how to fix that Problem?
I already tried different Browsers an clearing my cache...
